# Is the client allowed to choose challenge (nonce) in Digest HTTP authentication?

Tags: security, http, digest, digest-authentication

Digest authentication looks like a flavor of challenge-response mechanism: theres's a random string which is mixed with the password (MD5 or something) by both the client and the server and only the result of such mixing is sent over the network.

Usually the challenge ("nonce") is chosen by the server and sent to the client. [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) on digest authentication lists a sample "session" - the challenge ("nonce") is chosen by the server there. I tested the same with IIS on my machine - again, the challenge is generated by IIS.

But in some posts [like this one](https://developer.omniture.com/node/4237) the challenge is generated by the client - the client just generates a random string and sends a request with the challenge and the product of the password and that challenge.

Is the latter allowed and widely accepted? Is the client allowed to choose the challenge ("nonce")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTTP digest authentication, the server always generates the nonce.

However, HTTP authentication is extensible, and applications may implement other methods of authentication (beyond basic and digest). In the example you link to, the client is authenticating using [WSSE](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/12/17/dive.html), a form of authentication for (mainly SOAP-based) web services. In WSSE, the client generates the nonce.

Answer (score 1):

The [Digest Access Authentication scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3) is only a one-way authentication where the client authenticates itself to the server but *not* vice versa. Only the server issues a challenge that the client needs to be responded to correctly to be authenticated. So only the server knows if the client is authentic but the client doesn’t know if the server is authentic.

Now the linked code does the exact opposite: The client issues a challenge to the server to authenticate it. So the client knows if the server is authentic.

The best would be to use [mutual authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication).

Comment: In the linked example, the client doesn't issue a challenge to the server at all, it's pre-empting a challenge from the server.

Comment: @Phil: Are you sure? That would mean the client can *really* choose any nonce to authenticate itself. Then how does the authenticity validation look like on the server side? Well, fortunately, the communication is via HTTPS.

Comment: Take a read of the WSSE article I linked to in my answer. The client transmits its password hash and nonce, which the server uses to generate its own password hash to compare with one the client sent. It allows for a small optimisation over digest: there's no extra round-trip to get the nonce from the server.

Comment: @Gumbo: It doesn't really matter which side issues a nonce. The nonce is sent to the other party and both parties construct the product of the nonce and the secret, also the client sends the product to the server and the latter validates whether it matches the product it constructed itself.

Comment: @sharptooth: It *does* matter. If the nonce is not really used once you can do replay attacks (actually, that’s the only purpose of the nonce). So the server has to remember the nonces that already have been used. In that case it would be better if the server would only need to remember those nonces that it has actually issued.